# Kapacitor Write to file

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

.tick script:

```
stream
    |from()
        .measurement('httpjson_example')
    |alert()
        .crit(lambda: "temperature" <  70)
        // Whenever we get an alert write it to a file.
        .message('test')
        .log('/tmp/test.log')
```

Output test.log:

```
..."message":"test","CRITICAL","data":{"series":[{"name":"httpjson_example","tags":{"host":"influxdata","server":"http://...:8080/readings"},"columns":["time","dewPoint","heatIndex","humidity","response_time","temperature"],"values":[["2016-06-23T12:38:42Z",12.06,22.15,51.6,2.078549411,22.5]]}]}}
```

This script write to file but I just want string 'test' written.

Comment: Please write an explicit question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this isn't possible without a bit of work writing your own [UDF](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v0.13/nodes/u_d_f_node/).

If you'd like to see this feature in Kapacitor, open a [feature request](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/issues/new) that details your use case.